# how do i return in my class based view after updating data

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, web, django-models

here is my views.py function:

```
class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ['first_name','last_name','username','gender','datetimepicker','p_photo','h_photo','subtitles','political_incline',
            'about_me','birthplace','lives_in','country','province','city','occupation',
            'relationship_status','website','phone_number','religious_belifs','political_incline',
            'facebook','twitter','RSS','dibble','spotify']
```

urls.py

```
url(r'^updateprofile/(?P<pk>\d+)/$',views.ProfileUpdateView.as_view(success_url='/postlist/')),
```

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

add a succes url as below in your view

```
success_url = reverse_lazy('the_page_required')
```

if you want to go to your detail view you can define this way also.

```
def get_success_url(self):
         return reverse('detail_view_url', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```